# Струшувати та обтрушувати - синоніми?

Tags: синоніми

> [Струшувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/strushuvaty) 1. перех., з кого—чого. Збивати, скидати що-небудь з поверхні чогось. 2. перех. Трусячи, звільняти дерево, кущ від плодів. 3. перех. Трусячи, збивати що-небудь.
>
> [Обтрушувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/obtrushuvaty) 1. Струшуючи, постукуючи і т. ін., збивати, скидати з поверхні чого-небудь пил, сміття, сніг і т. ін. 2. з чого і без додатка. 3. Скидати, обсипати листя, пелюстки, плоди і т. ін. (про дерева, квіти, колосся і т. ін.).

[Синоніми](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh)

> Слово струшувати має наступні синоніми:
>
> (з себе) обтрушувати
>    (чим) трясти
>    стрясати
>   (термометр) збивати
>   (головою) стріпувати
>   (апатію) скидати
>   (груші) трусити

Не зовсім зрозуміла чи можна замінити струшувати на обтрушувати, наприклад коли говоримо про сніг. 
З себе сніг струшуємо/обрушуємо, а з рослин лише обтрушуємо? 
  Наприклад, можна сказати "струшувати сніг з сосен взимку обов'язково " чи лише "обтрушувати сніг з сосен взимку обов'язково"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слова **"струшувати"** й **"обтрушувати"** - не синоніми.

**"Струшувати"** вказує що об'єкт зазнає ***вібрації***: *струшувати термометер*, *струшувати шейкер з коктейлем*, *струс мозку*.

**"Обтрушувати"** вказує що з об'єкта ***відпадають дрібні шматки*** чогось: *обтрусити машину від снігу*, *обтрусити всі ябулука з яблуні*.

Різницю між цими словами видно в реченні:

***Обтрушувати*** пляшку шамапанського від пилу потррібно обережно, не **струшуючи** її.

Як синоніми "струшувати" і "обтрушувати" можна вживати в ситуації якщо ви щось  трусите щоб обтрусити: *струситися/обтруситися від снігу*.